# Could the assumption of superconductivity explain unexplained geomagnetic behaviors?

Tags: magnetic-fields, superconductivity, geophysics

Science recently published an [article regarding a new discovery in superconductivity](http://news.sciencemag.org/chemistry/2015/08/stinky-hydrogen-sulfide-smashes-superconductivity-record); that the metallic form of hydrogen sulfide is superconducting at high temperature (relative to absolute zero).

I've also read that the metallic forms of gases occur only under the most extreme pressures, and wondered if this new discovery could have a connection with geomagnetism - and if superconducting processes could be taking place within planets?

I've also heard geomagnetism is not fully explained. So assuming that superconducting processes could take place within the planet, could their existence possibly lead to explanations of some of the unknown reasons geomagnetism behaves as it does?

Comment: I think the core of Jupiter is in a metallic hydrogen state.  We know that Jupiter has a strong magnetic field but I am not sure enough about the details of a metallic hydrogen dynamo to give an answer.  I do know that many neutron star models use a superconducting assumption for the crust of the star (and inner regions too).  In many plasmas, the conductivity is high enough that they are often approximated as superconducting (think stars).  But superconductivity in a plasma locks in the magnetic field, not repels it like Type-I superconductors...